# Pattern to define dependency between classes, and the order they must be initialized

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a load procedure that needs loaded objects to be initialized in a certain order, depending on the classes they belong to. Some classes hold references to other classes and depend on those other classes having been initialized first.

Right now, I define the order with a static number field in each class. The programmer is responsible of coming up with the number value. I can then sort objects by this number and initialize them in the correct order.

```
public interface ILookUpCollectible
{     
    // this is the number the classes get sorted by before initializing
    int LoadPostProcessOrder { get; }    
}


 // start initializing, sort them first
 // sort:
        var sortedList = list.OrderBy(l => l.LoadPostProcessOrder);

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in sortedList) 
        {
            item.LoadPostProcess(sn);
            i++;              
        }
```

Is there a better way to do this? I would like each class to explicitly say which other classes it depends on (most often because it contains references to those classes), and then derive the order from that.

Comment: Do theses classes have static references to each other? It sounds like you want to make them into instances and make the dependencies explicit constructor parameters.

Comment: A lot of IoC/DI containers can construct objects like this, automatically discovering the dependencies and injecting them into the constructors, what it looks like you need is a DI container, like Unity (or any other one).

Comment: The classes/objects can reference each other through global static collections if that is what you mean.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to think the classes as parents and children? In this case the initialization of each object has as last line `InitializeChildren()`. In this routine you have a loop running through all children of the same level to start their initializers. Thus you trigger an initialization cascade down the full hierarchie...